# How to import titanium project from eclipse for run as a normal android project?

Tags: android, titanium

I developed one project using titanium framework. Now i want to import that project from eclipse for run as a normal android project. I had successfully import that project with some error from eclipse.

**(in manifest file have this error Class ti.modules.titanium.ui.TiTabActivity does not exist ,Class ti.modules.titanium.media.TiVideoActivity does not exist**, I removed this activity from manifest and error gone)**

But when I run the project it throws following exception.

```
    12-21 17:53:50.282: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(464): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception    
    12-21 17:53:50.292: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(464): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.mozilla.javascript.UniqueTag
    12-21 17:53:50.292: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(464):     at org.appcelerator.titanium.kroll.KrollBridge.<init>(KrollBridge.java:35)
    12-21 17:53:50.292: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(464):     at org.appcelerator.titanium.TiContext.createTiContext(TiContext.java:724)
    12-21 17:53:50.292: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(464):     at org.appcelerator.titanium.TiRootActivity.onCreate(TiRootActivity.java:64)
    12-21 17:53:50.292: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(464):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    12-21 17:53:50.292: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(464):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
```

The splash screen only display after that, application will be terminated.
I need this for testing the application in a release mode.From titanium I can only test the application in debug mode.

Please anyone help me to solve this problem.

Thanks

Comment: yes Aaron I can utilize that too..but, is that a build/android valid android project? how do i run that valid android project from eclipse? thats my actual problem.

Comment: I create new android project from eclipse and replace that project file with that build/android files and run that application that time too i got the same exception

Answer (score 0):

You should not have to import it, there is a project already set up in the **[PROJECT]/build/android/** directory that you should be able to utilize

Comment: yes Aaron I can utilize that too..but, is that a build/android valid android project? how do i run that valid android project from eclipse? thats my actual problem..

Comment: I create new android project from eclipse and replace that project file with that build/android files and run that application that time too i got the same exception

Answer (score 0):

Its using the libraries which are under your user home directory. Search for titanium.jar and you will see what I mean. Adjust your eclipse project to include those libraries and that should take care of it